# Jfrog CLI - build-add-git - how to access restricted JIRA

Tags: jfrog-cli

I am trying to capture JIRA issues like following however the JIRA used needs login credentials and I don't see way to pass JIRA credentials or access JIRA issues without credentials. How can I pass credentials in issues.yml? or is there a way to still access JIRA issues without credentials?

jf rt bag $BUILD_NAME $IMAGE_TAG --config issues.yml --project=$PROJECT

I was expecting to capture JIRA issues however JIRA is not accessible since it needs credentials.